# Disable scoring in Elastic Search and improve search performance

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to improve the speed and performance of my search queries.

Currently, I am using filtered queries and also applying the "fuzziness" parameter on some of the fields in my index while searching. I have already kept the fields as "not_analyzed" to improve performance.
The query is equivalent to the SQL query (Select from where =).

Also, while performing analysis on my query in QueryProfiler, i found that boost query is consuming a certain amount of time. I am not concerned with the scoring of the records and wish to fetch the data as it is searched.
For that, I am planning to set the "norms" parameter to "false" while insertion and search operations.

What other steps should I follow to disable boosting & scoring and to fasten the search operations?
And what properties should I enable/ disable in order to achieve the specified purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the query. Its difficult to answer without exactly seeing the query.

Comment: use constantscore query?